# android ndk build error lacks setup.mk

Tags: android-ndk

I am new to ndk and a I am trying to run helloJni project given in android ndk. I am getting this error. I have tried all possibilities still can't get rid of it. Please help.

so when i do
**ndk-build** i get this error message.

```
........./android-ndk-r8e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk:73: *** Android NDK:  Toolchain arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 lacks a setup.mk in ........../android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6    .  Stop.
```

I am using mac os x 10.8.4

GNU Make 3.81

I am missing something but I can't figure that out.

Comment: Do you have this `android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/setup.mk` file on the disk? Sometimes, reinstall NDK is the best solution.

Comment: The problem was already fixed by re-installing the sdk thanks for help